# How to run Spring 3.2 project in Tomcat V6.0.45

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I need to develop a spring project. Requirements are as follows:

- Spring - 3.0
- Hibernate - 3.0
- MySql 5.5
- Tomcat 6.0
- JDK 1.7

I am not using `web.xml` instead I am using java configuration.When I am trying to run my project on Tomcat v6.0 (by right click in eclipse on project -> Run at Server) it is saying that this project can not be run on any server. I have no idea how to run this project.
My pom.xml is as follows :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>lab.testme</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>testme3.0</name>
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.32</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.55</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My Facets setting is as follow :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.7"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>
</faceted-project>
```

I searched some articles and tried to change `jst.web` to `2.4` instead of `3.1` but it is not working. If I am trying to edit `Project Facets` through eclipse it is giving me error as `Can not change version of project facet dynamic web module to 2.5`. Kindly suggest me how to run this project?

Comment: You didn't even mention *how* you are running your project. It sounds like you're using your IDE's Tomcat integration.

Comment: @kryger : I am running my project by right clicking on project in eclipse -> Run at server. Then it show me a dialog box to select server when I try to select v6.0 then i got above error

Comment: Note that tomcat 6 as well as spring 3.2 will hit eol end of this year and you may not get important security updates anymore once your project goes live.

Comment: Tomcat 6 is a servlet 2.5 container and requires a web.xml. You need at lest tomcat 7 to run without a web.xml. Another thing your dependencies are a mess, you are mixing multiple spring versions (and maybe also hibernate) never mix jars of versions of a framework, that is trouble bound to happen. See http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: @zapl : yes, I have read about it but my company is not caring about it so I have to build it with above configuration

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thank you for this. I really hope it will help. I am creating a new p[roject with web.xml. Hope everything will go well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java based configuration for the web (using a `ServletContainerInitializer` which in turn for Spring will use a `WebApplicationInitializer`) is a Servlet 3.0 feature. Tomcat 6 supports the Servlet 2.5 specification and as such will not support java based configuration. In short when using Tomcat 6 you MUST use a `web.xml`. See [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for information on which servlet specification is supported by which Tomcat version.

To fix either upgrade to Tomcat 7 or use a `web.xml`.